# Your app, extension, and/or linked framework appears to contain code designed explicitly with the capability to change your app’s behavior

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Like many people, I received this today:

> Dear Developer,
>
> Your app, extension, and/or linked framework appears to contain code designed explicitly with the capability to change your app’s behavior or functionality after App Review approval, which is not in compliance with section 3.3.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement and App Store Review Guideline 2.5.2. This code, combined with a remote resource, can facilitate significant changes to your app’s behavior compared to when it was initially reviewed for the App Store. While you may not be using this functionality currently, it has the potential to load private frameworks, private methods, and enable future feature changes.
>
> This includes any code which passes arbitrary parameters to dynamic methods such as dlopen(), dlsym(), respondsToSelector:, performSelector:, method_exchangeImplementations(), and running remote scripts in order to change app behavior or call SPI, based on the contents of the downloaded script. Even if the remote resource is not intentionally malicious, it could easily be hijacked via a Man In The Middle (MiTM) attack, which can pose a serious security vulnerability to users of your app.
>
> Please perform an in-depth review of your app and remove any code, frameworks, or SDKs that fall in line with the functionality described above before submitting the next update for your app for review.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

But:

- [I do **not** use Rollout.io](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73640)
- [I do **not** use JSPatch](https://github.com/bang590/JSPatch/issues/746)
- I do **not** use weex: [incubator-weex](https://github.com/apache/incubator-weex) or [weex-devtool-iOS](https://github.com/weexteam/weex-devtool-iOS)
- I do **not** use javascript frameworks like React Native or Ionic
- I do **not** use javascript
- I do **not** use any of the quoted methods in my Swift 3 app.

I have no idea what is causing the warning.

---

Edit: the answer was...[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42665421/1033581)

Comment: Posted just 20 minutes earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662028/are-performselector-and-respondstoselector-banned-by-app-store

Comment: I closed as duplicate because even if I don't use rollout.io, there are other libs which use JSPatch secretly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42665421/1033581