# Can install module on iOS apps after install?

Tags: ios, dynamic, module

Is there any way to download module or extension on my iOS apps after install on iPhone(like mini software)? Is exist standard structure in iOS for this?

Comment: This is pretty much specifically forbidden by the app store guidelines.

Comment: Technically, it may be possible (Rollout.io, JSPatch, etc.), but in practice you'd be rejected by Apple. See: [Your app, extension, and/or linked framework appears to contain code designed explicitly with the capability to change your app’s behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662173/y)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are performSelector and respondsToSelector banned by App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662028/are-performselector-and-respondstoselector-banned-by-app-store)