# IPA (built by Xamarin.iOS) be rejected by Apple Store

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

After uploading my application to the Apple Store, I received this email from Apple:

> Guideline 2.5.2 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> During review, your app installed or launched executable code, which
>   is not permitted on the App Store. Specifically, your app uses the
>   itms-services URL scheme to install an app. Important Information As a
>   result of violating this guideline, your app’s review has been
>   delayed. Future submissions of this app, and other apps associated
>   with your Apple Developer account, will also experience a delayed
>   review. Deliberate disregard of the App Store Review Guidelines and
>   attempts to deceive users or undermine the review process are
>   unacceptable and is a direct violation Section 3.2(f) of the Apple
>   Developer Program License Agreement. Continuing to violate the Terms &
>   Conditions of the Apple Developer Program will result in the
>   termination of your account, as well as any related or linked
>   accounts, and the removal of all your associated apps from the App
>   Store. We want to provide a safe experience for users to get apps and
>   a fair environment for all developers to be successful. If you believe
>   we have misunderstood or misinterpreted the intent of your app, you
>   may submit an appeal for consideration or provide additional
>   clarification by responding directly to this message in Resolution
>   Center in iTunes Connect.

I have read this existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662028/are-performselector-and-respondstoselector-banned-by-app-store). And then I removed the usage of `JSPatch`.

However, I received the same email after upload again.

I then checked my project: there are no method like dlopen() or dlsym() used?

So, what is causing this issue? Or how can I found out what causes it?

Is there any difference from Xamarin.iOS and native iOS?

Comment: The message says you are using `itms-services` to install an app - search through your code for this string and remove that functionality

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: If you use native way to write native Apps using Objective-C / Swift, you probably won't encounter such problem. `Xamarin` is not a native way to write apps, and it might be banned by Apple at any time in future. Try switching to native ways to write apps.

Comment: If you use some third-party libraries, these private methods may be called in somexxx.a files. You can use the command line   nm -u xxx.a >> xxx.tx   t to print the information of the library and check that whether it contains the methods mentioned above .

Comment: @LucasZ Hey, you are right . It's caused by a VoIP library. I used the old version.Now I have updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use some third-party libraries, these private methods may be called in some`xxx.a` files. You can use the command line `nm -u xxx.a >> xxx.txt`  to print the information of the library and check that whether it contains the methods mentioned above .